# Django: How do I pass a form's input content from within a same page?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have just started on Django and am quite new to the whole thing.

I went through the whole tutorial on 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/ , which involves settings up the database and writing a simple form.

To start off my journey in Django, I plan to write a simple app that runs on localhost. And I have faced a issue in passing inputs form a form.

I have created a Name class in the models.py with 1 attribute

```
#name of the person
value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In my index link: http://localhost:8000/helloworld/, it contains a simple 1-input-field form as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'helloworld:hello' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Enter Name: <input size="80" name="link" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The aim of the form is to return the input data to the same link (http://localhost:8000/helloworld/) with a input message of:

```
"Welcome [NAME], Hello World"
```

In my views.py, the following method is written:

```
def hello(request,name):
    p = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=name)
    try:
       input_link = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['link'])
    except (KeyError, Link.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'helloworld/index.html',{
            'error_message': "You did not enter a name",
        })
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('helloworld:index', args=(p.value)))
```

How ever if I access the page http://localhost:8000/helloworld/, and entered a data in the field and click submit, it brings me to the page

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/helloworld/url%20'helloworld:hello'
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^helloworld/ ^$ [name='index']
^helloworld/ ^(?P<pk>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^helloworld/ ^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$ [name='results']
^helloworld/ ^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
^admin/
The current URL, helloworld/url 'helloworld:hello', didn't match any of these.
```

The content in the urls.py was from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial04/#amend-urlconf

As requested, the content of urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from domparser import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

May I know how do I go about solving this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show urls.py ?

Comment: Did you try `action=""` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply an answer for this type. If you want to post to same `url` you are currently now.Try this and chenge `def hello(request, name)` to `def hello(request)`.

```
action=""
```

Otherwise if `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
url(r'^$', view="index", name="app_index"),
```

)

Try this

```
action="{% url app_index %}"
```

As i found, in yours you can apply

```
action="{% url helloworld:index %}"
```

Hope this helps

**For your answer updated**. Try this

```
<form method="post" action="{% url "index" %}">
```

Comment: hi, i did that and it posted me to the same link with a empty page instead of displaying the field again. may i know how do you display the expected input in the new page?

Comment: That posted the data and reload the html. Then what you want after `post`?

Comment: in the input field i would enter a name and after clicking submit i wish to display the message, Welcome [NAME], Hello World!

Comment: k, thet put a condition in view, `if request.method=='POST`: do your operations `request.POST[`link`]`, Then return HttpResponse("you message") or `render` new html with your `data`

Comment: actually i have already created a function in view as stated in my post above. how do I actually call it?

Answer (score 0):

You need change this line

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'helloworld:hello' %}">
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="{% 'helloworld:hello' %}">
```